# Excel Power Query fails to retrieve all dimension members

Tags: olap, olap-cube, powerquery

I am using Power Query to retrieve data from an Analysis Services cube.
The cube is created by 3rd party forecasting software, and contains the results of two analysis runs. The first is with four strategy forecasts calculated under one set of parameters; the second is with 1 different strategy forecast calculated under another set of parameters.

So, strategy is a dimension in the generated cube, and there should be 5 members.

However, where my cube is has just been navigated to with no dimensions yet expanded,

```
Cube.Dimensions(myCube){[Name="Strategy"]}[Data]
```

returns a cube table of one column [Strategy].[Strategy].[Strategy] and only 4 rows, each of which contains the display name or caption of a strategy from the first run. The single strategy of the second run does not appear.

Strangely, it can be made to appear along with the other 4 if the cube is expanded to contain other dimensions or measures. Even more strangely, I can see the 5th member in the  table that I wish to extract, and can filter it explicitly, but a simple operation like Table.TransformColumns or Table.RowCount yields a result where the rows of the 5th member have vanished or been ignored.

This query

```
AnalysisServices.Database(myServer, myCatalog, [Query="SELECT [Strategy].[Strategy].Children ON 0 FROM [myCubeName]"])
```

... yields a table of one row and 5 columns. The column names are the Member Ids of all 5 strategies. The row contains 365 in each cell, which must be an irrelevant default measure.

The 5th item appears reliably when connecting with different methods (legacy Excel connection methods, VBA ADOMD code).

So, somehow the 5th member is in the cube, but it doesn't appear in Cube.Dimensions on its own, and is dropped from the result set if not explicitly retained with a filter.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here? My understanding of OLAP/cubes is quite basic. If there are any tests I could do/ask a DBA to do, please be specific.

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache or using "Refresh"?